# How to fetch from a branch, if I made changes on online GitHub editor?

Tags: git, github

So I'm working on a project on GitHub, and submitted one PR. In that PR, there was only one commit which I obtained by squashing all my small commits. Now I see that a line has typo, so I fixed it in online GitHub editor. The branch on which I'm working on is `issue#123`. This has a small commit message `Update settings.js`. 
I want to squash that commit also to my main single commit message, but I can't find a way to get that commit on my local machine.

I tried `git fetch upstream` followed by `git rebase upstream/master` 
I thought following should work well, but it is giving me an error

`git fetch origin issue#123:issue#123` 
and the error message states, 
 `! [rejected]            issue#123 -> issue#123  (non-fast-forward)` 
Instructions on my project says, never use `git mearge`, or `git pull`, If you want to use `git pull`, use it with `rebase` option.

Comment: In other words, How can I obtain same copy as my online forked copy on my local machine?

Comment: Are you running `git fetch origin` or `git fetch upstream`?

Comment: you might need to take a pull from your remote branch into your current branch, or merge the branch, then only your local branch will be updated with the changes in the remote branch.

Comment: Maybe [this link](https://hackernoon.com/git-push-and-pull-tips-and-tricks-7f9163539f02) can help you with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach would be to *reset* your local branch the the origin one:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout  issue#123 
git reset --hard origin/issue#123
```

(make sure you don't have any local work in progress: stash it first)

That is assuming you have fixed that branch on your remote forked, referenced by "origin".